# TypeError: pool.request(...).query(...).input is not a function

Tags: node.js, sql-server

In my NodeJS Backend server I have a set of routes that contains multiple 'get' requests and a 'post' request. All the 'get' requests are working perfectly but the 'post' request is giving me the following error.

```
TypeError: pool.request(...).query(...).input is not a function
    at Object.addCtms (D:\New CTMS Project\NewCTMS\ctms_normac\server\dboperations.js:86:8)
```

I understand the error but am not sure what to modify to make it work and following is the 'addCtms' function,

```
async function addCtms(ctms) {
    try {
      let pool = await  sql.connect(config);
      let insertCtms = await pool.request()
      .query("INSERT INTO ctms (shop_order, item_number, machine, supplier, feet_coil, Date_on, load_no, loadpc_signoff, pc_staff_load, unloadpc_signoff, pc_staff_unload, Date_off, ctms_id, complete)")
      .input('shop_order', sql.NChar(20), ctms.shop_order)
      .input('item_number', sql.NChar(20), ctms.item_number)
      .input('item_desc', sql.NChar(50), ctms.item_desc)
      .input('machine', sql.NChar(10), ctms.machine)
      .input('supplier', sql.NChar(20), ctms.supplier)
      .input('feet_coil', sql.NChar(10), ctms.feet_coil)
      .input('Date_on', sql.NChar(10), ctms.Date_on)
      .input('load_no', sql.NChar(15), ctms.load_no)
      .input('loadpc_signoff', sql.NChar(10), ctms.loadpc_signoff)
      .input('pc_staff_load', sql.NChar(10), ctms.pc_staff_load)
      .input('unloadpc_signoff', sql.NChar(10), ctms.unloadpc_signoff)
      .input('pc_staff_unload', sql.NChar(15), ctms.pc_staff_unload)
      .input('Date_off', sql.NChar(10), ctms.Date_off)
      .input('ctms_id', sql.NChar(15), ctms.ctms_id)
      .input('complete', sql.NChar(10), ctms.complete)
      return  insertCtms.recordsets;
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

The query for the 'ctms' table in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctms](
    [UNIQUE_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [shop_order] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [item_number] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [item_desc] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [machine] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [supplier] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [feet_coil] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Date_on] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [load_no] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [loadpc_signoff] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [pc_staff_load] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [unloadpc_signoff] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [pc_staff_unload] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [Date_off] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [ctms_id] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [complete] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ctms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UNIQUE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If need any more information to answer I'm happy to update the question. Thank you!

**---MODIFIED---**
Yes, I'm using `mssql` package, also
As the comments suggested I did change a few things in my 'addCtms' function. Now the good part/improvement is I'm able to post stuff to SQL Table without any error via `Postman`. But all the data I see in the SQL table is 'NULL'.

Here is the modified function :

```
async function addCtms(ctms) {
    try {
      let pool = await sql.connect(config);
      let insertCtms = await pool.request()
      .input('shop_order', sql.NChar(20), ctms.shop_order)
      .input('item_number', sql.NChar(20), ctms.item_number)
      .input('item_desc', sql.NChar(50), ctms.item_desc)
      .input('machine', sql.NChar(10), ctms.machine)
      .input('supplier', sql.NChar(20), ctms.supplier)
      .input('feet_coil', sql.NChar(10), ctms.feet_coil)
      .input('Date_on', sql.NChar(10), ctms.Date_on)
      .input('load_no', sql.NChar(15), ctms.load_no)
      .input('loadpc_signoff', sql.NChar(10), ctms.loadpc_signoff)
      .input('pc_staff_load', sql.NChar(10), ctms.pc_staff_load)
      .input('unloadpc_signoff', sql.NChar(10), ctms.unloadpc_signoff)
      .input('pc_staff_unload', sql.NChar(15), ctms.pc_staff_unload)
      .input('Date_off', sql.NChar(10), ctms.Date_off)
      .input('ctms_id', sql.NChar(15), ctms.ctms_id)
      .input('complete', sql.NChar(10), ctms.complete)
      .query("INSERT INTO ctms (shop_order, item_number, item_desc, machine, supplier, feet_coil, Date_on, load_no, loadpc_signoff, pc_staff_load, unloadpc_signoff, pc_staff_unload, Date_off, ctms_id, complete) values (@shop_order, @item_number, @item_desc, @machine, @supplier, @feet_coil, @Date_on, @load_no, @loadpc_signoff, @pc_staff_load, @unloadpc_signoff, @pc_staff_unload, @Date_off, @ctms_id, @complete)")
      return  insertCtms.recordsets;
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Following is how the data shows after it's inserted in to the SQL table. The first 4 records are manually inserted for demonstration how it should look alike.[image: SQL table]

And finally following is how I did try to insert data to test out the POST method via `Postman`. It returns a `201 Created` status and an empty array.[image]

Comment: Aside... don't use ordinal inserts like that, one day your code will break as columns are dropped and recreated. Always specify the column names e.g. `insert schema.table (column1, column2, ...) values (value1, value2, ...)`.

Comment: Are you using the [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) module? Since `.input()` is a function on the `Request` object have you tried to place `.query()` at the end of the call chain? e.g.: `request().input().input().input()...query()`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you much for your suggestions. Yes I do use `mssql` package, also I have modified the code as much as I can and got to a point that the 'POST' works with no error. But question I have now is whatever I try to insert it all 'POST' as 'NULL' values into the table. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to specify the length of your `nchar` fields in your `.input()` parameters, JS interprets those as function calls. Those are just data type definitions, so I use something more like this:

```
pool.request()
.input('param1', sql.VarChar, params.p1)
.input('param2', sql.Int,     params.p2)
.input('param3', sql.NChar,   params.p3)
.query(sqlStatement);
```

Where `params` is the parameter object and `sqlStatement` is a sql statement defined earlier.